# How to use a .bat file to run other .bat(s) and have each one in a seperate cmd prompt in different directory locations

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
    start cmd
    cd /d C:\U\O\D\L\D\M
    call runbot.bat
    cd /d C:\U\O\D\L\F
    call RunBossBot.bat
```

My issue is switching between cmd windows, it attempts to put everything in one window.
  Grateful for any help,
   Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start "" "c:\somewhere\runbot.bat"
start "" "c:\somewhere\RunBossBot.bat"
```

### Starting a Program

See `start /?` and `call /?` for help on all three ways.

### Specify a program name

```
c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

In a batch file the batch will wait for the program to exit. When
typed the command prompt does not wait for graphical
programs to exit.

If the program is a batch file control is transferred and the rest of the calling batch file is not executed.

### Use Start command

```
start "" c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

Start starts a program and does not wait. Console programs start in a new window. Using the /b switch forces console programs into the same window, which negates the main purpose of Start.

Start uses the Windows graphical shell - same as typing in WinKey + R (Run dialog). Try

```
start shell:cache
```

### Use Call command

Call is used to start batch files and wait for them to exit and continue the current batch file.

Comment: It worked thanks so much, now I am messing w/ start shell: to see what I can do

Comment: See my answer yesterday that list's `shell:`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549573/how-to-run-any-program-from-powershell-or-cmd/38549711#38549711